# Unfilter a SharePoint Filtered List view after entering first element

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I've created a customised view of a Document Library (i.e.  Column "Name" Contains "2017") and saved it as a separate view (i.e. 2017filter.aspx).  The result is fine, however after I clicked the view's item (i.e. a folder called "2017 ABC Company" and entered the folder, the list is empty (I assume because the "2017" filter is still active in the second view); is it possible to disable it after the URL click?

Answer (score 0):

Modify this view and go to Folders, select Show this view: In the top-level folder.

[image]

If you can't see this option, go to library settings->Advanced settings->set "Allow management of content types? " to Yes.

[image]

Comment: I modify the reply in above.

Comment: Did so, and I tried to modify the list view again, but it seems to have done nothing: https://imgur.com/a/84BEs

Comment: See my screenshot above, select " In the top-level folder"

Comment: ditto, but still the same - the filter is still applied.

Comment: Please provide some screenshots about the list view page for further research.